# OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument in PyCharm

Tags: python, datetime, pycharm, oserror

[image]I have got following code which works in google colab but unfortunately not in PyCharm:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/72197385/18745566

I got this Error:

OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument

Can anyone help me?
Thanks a lot[image]

Comment: Have you updated the folder path to the actual path which you are using?

Comment: make sure the directory is accessible and the path is correct

Comment: Yes, I and the curious thing is that the exact same code is working for google colab

Comment: set a tzinfo: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65564765/10197418

Comment: @SumSum can you show me all sub-dir in "Bilder"?

Comment: I dont have any subfolder in "Bilder", in this dir I only got the jpg images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `File -> Settings -> Project: -> Project Structure -> Click on Timestamp (folder) -> Click on Mark as Sources -> Apply -> OK.`

I hope it help you!